# 2 wire camera for image processing. Exists?

Tags: image-processing, camera, raspberry-pi, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am hoping someone can tell me if a 2 wire camera exists. I have had no luck finding one that is relatively cheap. The 2 wires have to carry the signal and power of the camera.

Basically I want to use a device like a Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone to process images.

HOWEVER, I want to utilise existing 2-wire (shielded twisted pair) cables in the field and have the image processing device in the central location.

Anyone know of such a thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any analogue camera can be assuming that you dont require PTZ telemetry to the camera.  You could also use something like this:

[Balun](http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/CCTV-Video-Baluns-s/89.htm)